# Include third party JS library into my drupal module

Tags: 8, theming

I want to include this [library](https://github.com/malsup/blockui) into my drupal module. Now I have two problems.

1. I wanted to use composer manager to get this library, but it's not available on packagist.org. So, I've tried to put it there manually to do not stuck on it. Path is MY_DRUPAL/vendor/malsup/jQuery.blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js
2. I want to attach this library via hook_page_attachments, but seems I don't know how to define this library in libraries.yml. The problem is that I cannot specify path to folder vendor/ from my_module.libraries.yml, because vendor/ located in root of drupal.

Could somebody give me an advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is JS library, not PHP library. There is no reason to get /vendor directory or composer involved. Just put the js into your module's directory(or subdirectory) and define entry in libraries file of your module.

Comment: But it's third party library. In D7 I put libraries like this, into sites/all/libraries. What the right solution for D8?

Comment: At the moment there is no right solution: https://www.drupal.org/node/2605130

Answer (score 1):

You still put them in the libraries folder (now you can also use a top-level `/libraries`folder).

You need the libraries module, just like in 7.x. I'm also not 100% sure how well it works now in 8.x, in the [JW Player module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jw_player), I'm just using it to detect the location of the files: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/jw_player/tree/jw_player.module?h=8.x-1.x#n206

Comment: It doesn't looks like a final solution but seems you're right. I have found that https://www.drupal.org/project/codesnippet is doing the same.